# Shotcode error on functions

Tags: shortcode

Hello i have this shortcode that is generating a error.

Can someone help?

```
add_shortcode('do-action', 'do_action_shortcode');

function do_action_shortcode($atts, $content = '') {
  ob_start();
  do_action($content);
  $out = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $out;
}
```

Comment: What kind of error? Do you have the function do_action defined?

Answer (score 1):

[`do_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) is a WordPress function for *running* action hooks. I assume that is what you are trying to do. Given that, The first parameter, the only one in your case, needs to be an action hook name. If you pass it a valid hook name and have a function attached to that hook, this code works.

In other words, if you set it up like this...

```
function do_action_shortcode($atts, $content = '') {
  ob_start();
  do_action($content);
  $out = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $out;
}
add_shortcode('do-action', 'do_action_shortcode');

function generic_cb() {
  echo 'generic content';
}
add_action('testhook','generic_cb');
```

... so that you have an action hooked to `testhook`, and use a shortcode like ...

```
[do-action]testhook[/do-action]
```

... in you post body. It does work.

[You should not be using hyphens in the shortcode name though.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Hyphens)

I don't know exactly which part of that you have wrong, but hopefully that working model (tested) will help you out.

The only way, I have found to actually generate an error is if `generic_cb` (in the example) is not defined. If you send a nonexistent hook name...

```
[do-action]notahook[/do-action]
```

... it just does nothing.